# How to exceute ipynb file in excel VBA code

Tags: python, vba, shell, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute some python scripts through VBA code.

".py" files are working pretty well, but i am struggling with ".ipynb" files

for example to ".py" files, I can run them by simple code below.

```
Sub run_python_script()

    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitonReturn As Boolean: waitonReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1   

    args = "path to something.py"
    wsh.Run "C:\Users\kingd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" & " " & args, windowStyle, waitonReturn

End Sub
```

On the other hand, ".ipynb" files does not work
when i just substitute the file path ('args', in case of the above code) to that of ".ipynb" file.

What is the most simple way to solve my problem?
(I am looking for the most simple, reliable way...)

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: `ipynb` is NOT python script (but some JSON with information about cells in `Juputer`) and it will NOT run directly with `python.exe`. You would have to covnvert `ipynb` to `py` (`juputer` should have function to convert or export it) Or you should use program which can run `ipynb` - like `jupyter`.